# Liquibase diff results in NullpointerException in ChangedIndexChangeGenerator.java:72

Tags: mysql, liquibase

using Liquibase 3.2.2 we face a problem with liquibase diffs mechanism for the automatic generation of a changelog to transform database schema A into database schema B.

We tried using the Liquibase diff function on two mysql databases. Whilst comparing, Liquibase throws a NullPointerException. 
Our schemas contain tables, views, foreign and primary key constraints. Diffing the reference database against an empty one works fine and a functional changeLog is created.

Any ideas what could be the cause in our old data model that causes the problems during the diff call?

Here's the exceptions stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.core.ChangedIndexChangeGenerator.fixChanged(ChangedIndexChangeGenerator.java:72)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorChain.fixChanged(ChangeGeneratorChain.java:118)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.ChangeGeneratorFactory.fixChanged(ChangeGeneratorFactory.java:122)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.generateChangeSets(DiffToChangeLog.java:167)
    at liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog.print(DiffToChangeLog.java:125)
    at liquibase.integration.ant.DiffDatabaseToChangeLogTask.executeWithLiquibaseClassloader(DiffDatabaseToChangeLogTask.java:47)
    at liquibase.integration.ant.BaseLiquibaseTask.execute(BaseLiquibaseTask.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 10 more
```

Your input is highly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Steven

Comment: You wrote version 3.2.2, but do you mean version 3.3.2? Because I am seeing the same problem from 3.3.0 and onwards. Downgrading to earlier releases such as 3.2.2 and 3.2.3 seems to work fine here.

Comment: oh yes, you are right. I ment 3.3.2. Sorry about that!

Comment: Upgrading to Liquibase 3.3.3 solved the problem for me.